# I want to split data that I get from API and convert it to date and Months

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's where I call the data from the API.

```dart
  Center(
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.5.h),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          data[index].waktu, //this will show "2021/03/11" but all I want is only '03' and convert it to month
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0.h),
          child: Text(
            data[index].waktu,//this will show "2021/03/11" but all I want is only '11'
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Can you explain how to get the only data that I want and convert it to a month name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DateFormat` from intl package to parse from your format, then format to what you need.

for exemple, for your first Text:
replace

```
data[index].waktu,
```

with

```
DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(data[index].waktu)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to format your `DateTime` object

Use

```dart
DateFormat('d').format(DateTime("2021/03/11") // 11
DateFormat('M').format(DateTime("2021/03/11") // 03
DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime("2021/03/11") // March
```

Comment: instead of `data[index].waktu,` put `DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime(data[index].waktu),`

Comment: @JulienV error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. this appeared

Comment: yeah indeed,it's incomplete, i'll repost a solution